# How to catch custom annotations in Spring @ExceptionHandler?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a custom annotation like this:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Documented
@PreAuthorize(AllowedForSystemUsers.condition)
public @interface AllowedForSystemUsers {
    String condition = "hasAnyRole({'ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER'})";
}
```

and I put the annotation in my `Controller` method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/search", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@AllowedForSystemUsers
public String searchRooms(@ModelAttribute Booking booking, Model model, long type) {

    //do something
}
```

My `ExceptionHandler` like this:

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = AccessDeniedException.class)
public ModelAndView accessDenied(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AccessDeniedException e) {

    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/error");
}
```

So when user have no auth as `ROLE_ADMIN` or `ROLE_USER`, an `AccessDeniedException` occurred and code run into `accessDenied()` method.

My question is how can I know if the `@AllowedForSystemUsers` annotation trigger this `AccessDeniedException`? Becouse the other code may also trigger `AccessDeniedException`

Thanks!

Comment: You need to throw your exception in controller. For executing global exception handler you need to throw the exception from somewhere else.

Comment: You could consider making subclass of `AccessDeniedException` and throw it while in `@AllowedForSystemUsers` processing

Comment: @SungJinSteveYoo for example?

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna so you mean I can't use Spring Security default `AccessDeniedException`?

Comment: Why don't you use built'in @PreAuthorize, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/el-access.html#method-security-expressions

Comment: You can use spring default `AccessDeniedException` using HttpSecurity `http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());` In this handler you can handle your own specific exception.

Comment: To your specific question: You can ask the `request` (has it `contextPath = '/search'` and `method=POST`?), to distinguish, whether this (same type of) exception comes from a distinct controller invocation.

Comment: @Young Why do you want to know this at all?

Comment: @HerrDerb Because I want provide different message with each custom annotations, so I want set different message in my exception handler.

Comment: @xerx593 yeah, it's really can know which method occurred this `AccessDeniedException`, but I have to judge each method. I want to know if there a way to deal it just in annotation level, because one annotation show one message is enough.

Comment: @YOUNG I'm not sure if this is the right approach. Why would you have different messages for a situation where the user is unauthorized? What you want to do, seems more of a task for the front end.

Comment: @HerrDerb For example, when user unauthorized by `@AllowedForSystemUsers` annotation I want to show error message A, when user unauthorized by `@AllowedForAdminUsers` annotation I want to show error message B, and so on... So I want to know, which annotation unauthorized the user.

Comment: @YOUNG usually a system is not giving a user any hint, why he is not authorized. He simply is not authorized. This is a security issue. Further more, a user which is not `admin` should not be able to invoke any admin action on the front end. This is an issue of usability and will resolve this problem.

Comment: @HerrDerb Thanks. But I think if a user not login and when he want do something that have to log in, I want let him know the reason .

Comment: I don't see the problem, because then you have an `Unauthorized` exception. You can let the user know that he is not logged in of course. Or better, you don't let him be able to do any action if he is not logged in. E.g. Disable or hide the button.

Comment: @HerrDerb Yeah it's a good way.But in my case it's  a little complicated.It's a hotel booking site, I want let user see the booking button and can search available rooms even he is not logged in, but when he want to booking a room, he get like  `Please login first` message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A system should not give a user any hint, why he is not authorized. He simply is not authorized. This is a security issue. Further more, a user which is not admin should not be able to invoke any admin action on the front end at all. This is an issue of usability.

You want the following (Include context information the next time within your question):

> I want the user to see the booking button and to be able to search available rooms
>   even he is not logged in, but when he wants to book a room, he gets a massage
>   like Please login first message

This is absolutely no problem. If the users, which is currently not logged in, is pressing the `Book` button, I have to assume the server will response with a [`401` HTTP code](https://httpstatuses.com/401). In your front end you simply react to this response status code, by showing the user the information, that he is apparently not logged in or whatever you want to do. There is absolutely no need, that the server needs to tell you why he responded with a `401`.